# Opposite Reactions to the tips: Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle

Grandpa is visiting his cousin Bob. They go to a nice Restaurant for Lunch. The food and service were great. Waitress was charming. She brings the bill. It is 22 dollars. Bob says to Grandpa "I will pick up this tab".

He puts exactly 30 dollars with the bill in the tray. The waitress comes and picks up the bill and the money, looks at it. She is not happy. Bob and Grandpa get a nasty look from her.

For the dinner they go to another Restaurant in the nearby town. The service was bad. The food came very late. The waitress was grumpy. She finally brought the bill. It was 67 dollars. Unhappy Grandpa said: " I will  take it".

> He puts exactly 67 dollars in the bill tray. They both walk out. The waitress comes running out of the Restaurant with the bill tray and money in her hand. With a big smile on her face she says: "Thank you so much!".

What happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> They have lunch in a restaurant just south of the US-Canada border. Bob pays in Canadian dollars. 30 Canadian dollars is about 23 US dollars, so the waiters thinks she's getting a lousy tip.
>  They then have dinner just north of the border, and grandpa pays with US dollars. 67 US dollars is about 88 Canadian dollars.

Comment: I guess you meant 23 US dollars, not 29.

Answer (score 12):

What happened is that

> Bob is Canadian and Grandpa is American

The first waitress was not happy because:

> Bob gave 30 CAD (22.7 USD) for a 22 USD bill

The second waitress was quite happy because:

> Grandpa gave 67 USD (88.54 CAD) for a 67 CAD bill

Comment: While both xhienne and Abigail have similar answers it is important to note that the First Restaurant was on the US side and the second was on the Canadian side of the border. Which Abigail did. So +1 for him too

Comment: @DEEM Why not choose her answer then? Moreover, Abigail was first to answer.

Comment: Just 53 seconds ahead of me ;-) Thank you for her @DEEM